# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n}$ converges uniformly on $[\pi /2 , 3\pi /2]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I must show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n}$ converges uniformly on $[\pi /2 , 3\pi /2]$ - I know that it holds on $[\pi /2 , \pi ]$, which should also be sufficient as a proof, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

We want to be able to use Dirichlet uniform convergence test

So we need that
i)
 `1/n is monotonous decreasing function`

ii)
`1/n uniformly converges to 0` (which it does since it doesn't depend on variable x)

iii)

$$
(\exists M>0)(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(\forall x\in [\pi/2,3\pi/2])
$$

$$
\left | \sum_{m=1}^{n} \sin(mx)  \right | \le M
$$

We can prove that by

$$
\left | \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}\sum_{m=1}^{n} \sin{mx}\sin{\frac{x}{2}}  \right | = \left | \frac{1}{2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}\sum_{m=1}^{n} (\cos{\frac{(2m-1)x}{2}}-\cos{\frac{(2m+1)x}{2}})  \right | =
$$

$$
\left | \frac{\cos{\frac{x}{2}}-\cos{\frac{(2n+1)x}{2}}}{2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}} \right | \le \left | \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}} \right |
$$

So when $x\in [\pi/2,3\pi/2])$ we know $\frac{x}{2} \in [\pi/4,3\pi/4]$

$$
\max_{x \in [\pi/4,3\pi/4]} \left | \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}} \right | = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Hence using Dirichlet uniform convergence test we conclude that beginning function series uniformly converges on $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$